# /ds_extras_node_page_view consuming 51% of memory - Drupal 7

Tags: php, performance, drupal-7

I am working on a drupal 7 website. This website goes down a couple times a month for 4 to 5 minutes.
Looking at the new relic report it says : **/ds_extras_node_page_view consumes 52% to 92%** of the memory while loading which causes the site to go down.
This is function in the display suite module in drupal Core.
Not sure what would be the possible solution for this. Could you please help me reason this out.

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Drupal core version 7.32 and Display Suite 7.x-1.8

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

1. Display suite is a contributed module. It is not a part of core.
2. Display suite is known for being resource heavy.

If resources are an issue then I would recommend finding a way to do the things that you are doing with Display suite and instead doing those things with either core's apis or a lighter weight contributed module.

Most of the time Display Suite is used for simple things such as adding a view mode. I would recommend the lighter weight [entity view mode module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) if this is all you are utilizing in Display Suite.